# Debugging issue in VSCode using Flutter Bloc: Debugger pauses at an unexpected location

Tags: flutter, dart, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, flutter-bloc

I'm encountering a debugging issue in my Flutter code while using Flutter Bloc. The problem I'm facing is that when I set a breakpoint in my Bloc, instead of pausing the code execution there, it pauses at the following location in bloc.dart file:

```dart
try {
    _emitters.add(emitter);
    await handler(event as E, emitter);
} catch (e) {
    print('Exception in handler: $e');
}
```

Also, I have another projects where I used fluter Bloc and when I try to debug them it does not happen the same mistake.

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this debugging issue. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.